# Isomporphism two languages.

Tags: regular-language, monoid

Let $A$ be an alphabet. Let $X,L \subset A^*$ $L$ is regular.
Let $$X^{-1}L := \{ w \in A^* \mid \exists x \in X\ \  xw \in L \} $$
 $$LX^{-1} := \{ w \in A^* \mid \exists x \in X\ \   wx \in L \} $$

As we know, languages are free monoids. Is there any isomorphism from $X^{-1} L \to L X^{-1} $?

I was trying to find something but I got stuck.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Languages are subsets of free monoids, but in general neither monoids nor free monoids.

Comment: ok. But I still wait for answer.

Comment: Then you have to specify what "isomorphism" should mean? Do you mean "bijection"?

Comment: Probably bijection. But I am not sure. I have to prove some property for $X^{-1}L $. And I would like show that this language is equivalent to $LX^{-1}$ and then prove those properties for $LX^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: look at $L=a^*b$ and $X=\{b\}$ and calculate $LX^{-1}$ as well as $X^{-1}L$.

Comment: I see, it's not possible. I gave a counterexample.,
Hmm, so you may help me with my proof?

Comment: @user180834: If you have a counterexample, then you know that an isomorphism isn't possible, so this *is* your proof.

Comment: yes, I mean prove another task.